# ¿Por qué en la página W3schools dice que el método MSQLI_FETCH_ARRAY() y todos sus derivados están deprecados?

Tags: php

Necesito saber si se trata de un error de la página w3schools, o si es verdad que ya existen nuevos métodos para retornar lo de una base de datos. Porque hace poco en esta página aprendí a retornar datos con **msqli_fetch_array**, **msqli_fetch_row** y **msqli_fetch_assoc**..pero ahora w3school dice que están obsoletos, pero ni siquiera especifica las nuevas formas. Hasta hace poco he estado practicando con estos métodos pero ahora no sé si estoy perdiendo mi tiempo.

[deprecated link](https://www.w3schools.com/php7/php7_ref_mysqli.asp)

Comment: Supongo que debe ser un error de la pagina w3school. La documentación oficial de PHP no dice nada de esto al respecto. https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Comment: Hasta donde se solo esta deprecated *mysqli_fetch*

Comment: Parece que si, es un error de la pagina. Lo que ellos quisieron decir es que msql_fetch_array esta deprecado, pero se han confundido y han escrito msqli_fetch_array.... y, ahora que reviso, este metodo ni siquiera existe...es fetch_array, fetch_row, fetch_assoc...alguien deberia avisarles

Comment: @natan, respecto a tu pregunta si ya esta solucionada, por favor, considera cerrarla. Respecto a avisarles a los de `W3Shool` **yo ya lo hice**, te dejo [este enlace](http://w3schools.invisionzone.com/topic/59340-php-7-mysqli-functions-page-it-show-wrong-info-about-deprected-functions/) para que la próxima vez si te interesa hacerlo, sepas como. Saludos!